# Complex series expansion of a particular form using formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

Write down an expansion of the form:

$\sum c_nz^2$

$ f = \frac {1}{(z^2-1)(z^2-9)}$

from a formula:
$\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \frac{1}{(a-b)} \sum (z^n (\frac{1}{b^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{ a^{n+1}})) $

could I apply it to this equation then? ($z^2$ instead of $z$)

so
$a=1$, 
$b=9$:

$f = \frac{-1}{8} (\sum (z^{2n} (\frac{1}{9^{n+1}} -1))$

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this should be fine. It's helpful to note that
$$\frac1{z-b}-\frac1{z-a}={a-b\over(z-a)(z-b)}.$$
The identity now follows by dividing both sides by $a-b$ and expanding using geometric series.

Comment: @Tim_Raczkowski could you also check my derivation? it should be the same if I were to flip the a and b? well it must be.

Comment: Yes, that would, of course, be true.